# OpenGL Tube Along a Path

Tags: c, opengl

So I'm playing around with OpenGL and trying to figure out how to draw some fun shapes.

Right now, I'm working on a tube. I can draw a straight tube just fine with:

```
void tube(GLfloat radius, GLfloat segment_length) {
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_NONE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

    glPushMatrix(); {
        GLfloat z1 = 0.0;
        GLfloat z2 = segment_length;

        GLfloat y_offset = 0.0;
        GLfloat y_change = 0.00;

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            glPushMatrix(); {
                glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP); {
                    for (i = 360; i >= 0; i--) {
                        GLfloat theta = i * pi/180;
                        GLfloat x = radius * cos(theta);
                        GLfloat y = radius * sin(theta) + y_offset;

                        glVertex3f(x, y, z1);
                        glVertex3f(x, y, z2);
                    }
                } glEnd();
            } glPopMatrix();

            // attach the front of the next segment to the back of the previous
            z1 = z2;
            z2 += segment_length;

            // make some other adjustments
            y_offset += y_change;
        }
    } glPopMatrix();
}
```

However, I haven't figured out how to make the tube follow any predefined path like a spiral, or even a simple line. If you change y_change to something like 0.01, it will draw each tube segment offset an additional 0.01 in the y direction. That great, but how can I make each segment point in that direction? In other words, right now, each segment is drawn so that they all face the same direction, and the direction is not the direction of the tube (since with y_change = 0.01, the direction is slightly "up").

I'm not sure how to proceed. I've played with vectors by getting the vector between the previous segment and the current one, but I'm not really sure what to do with it past that.

Comment: Have you looked at (for one example) the Red Book's torus example? http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/redbook/torus.c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The idea is called *path controlled extrusion*, i.e. you have a basic n dimensional shape and extrude it along a n+1 dimensional curve. I can read your face: "Huh, what is he saying?"

So here's a coarse outline. First you need a function that maps a value, usually called t, to a continous, smooth curve in space. For example a screw:

```
path(t): R → R³, t ↦ ( a·sin(k·t), b·cos(k·t), c·t )
```

The idea is, to find a localized coordinate base to define your vertices positions in relation to that path - it makes sense, that one of the coordinate is aligned in parallel to the path, so you want to find it's tangent. This is done by finding its gradient:

```
tangent(t): R → R³, t ↦ ( k·a·cos(k·t), -k·b·sin(k·t), c ) = d/dt path(t)
```

So this is the local base vector that's pointing along the curve, with the origin of the local coordinate system at the point `t` of the curve.

But we need two other vectors, to form a full 3d base. It is usually a good choice to have the second base point perpendicular to the curvature, which you get by finding the curl of the tangent:

```
normal(t): R → R³, t ↦ ( -k²·a·sin(k·t), -k²·b·cos(k·t), 0 ) = d/dt tangent(t) = d²/dt² path(t)
```

This is called the normal.

The thrid base vector can be obtained, taking the cross product of normal and tangent, yielding the binormal. I'll let you figure that one out as an exercise.

Now to extrude a shape along the curve, you've to split the path into segments, simply by iterating `t` over a choosen range, giving you the local origin. The points of your extruded shape are relative to this origin path(t). Let's say your shape consists of the points P_n in the x-y plane then:

```
for t in [k..l]:
    for p in P_n:
        yield_vertex( path(t).x + binormal(t).x * p.x, 
                      path(t).y + normal(t).y * p.y, 
                      path(t).z )
```

I'll leave it to you, figuring out how to adapt this to OpenGL, after all you should learn something by thinking about it. If you can't solve it until tomorrow, I'll gladly give you the solution, but it's usually more fun figuring things out by your own.

Comment: +1: Excellent answer. If you're interested in a piece-wise linear function, you can find the tangent as the average of v(n) (the vector from the last point to this one) and v(n+1) (the vector from this point to the next one).

Comment: awesome, thanks for this answer. I'm going to spend some time working through this. I'll let you know what progress I make (although school and work may consume some of my recreation time that I set aside for this).

Comment: yeah, I'm afraid that my math skills aren't up to this (part of the problem may be that I don't entirely understand your notation). I can't seem to translate that to OpenGL, it seems like not matter what I do, the tube segments always face one direction.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce it to a [previously-solved problem](http://linas.org/gle/).

Comment: The GLE extrusion library is a little bit outdated, some bugs , and need some rework.

Answer (score 1):

This api is able to do extrusion along a path:

http://www.visualizationlibrary.org/documentation/pag_guide_extrusion.html

Answer (score 0):

The **physics** interpretation is good one for your extrusion problem(in algebraic-vectorial point of view):

[https://cobalt.rocky.edu/~ulrich.hoensch/FS_2016/MAT275/Lecture%20Notes/Lecture%2013_5%20The%20Binormal%20Vector%20and%20Torsion.pdf](https://cobalt.rocky.edu/%7Eulrich.hoensch/FS_2016/MAT275/Lecture%20Notes/Lecture%2013_5%20The%20Binormal%20Vector%20and%20Torsion.pdf)

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368634/direction-of-velocity-vector-in-3d-space

https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Map%3A_University_Calculus_(Hass_et_al)/12%3A_Vector-Valued_Functions_and_Motion_in_Space/12.5%3A_Tangential_and_Normal_Components_of_Acceleration

https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node24.html

In fact can see that :

1)path(t) is r(alpha(t)) where alpha(t)=kt with k=2PI/w
r(t) - position vector with 3d(euclidian space) coordinates : x(t),y(t),z(t)
alpha - the angle at center
w - the scalar angular speed = 2PI/k = (r x v)/||r^2|| here x is vector product

2. tangent(t) is v(t) tangential speed = dr / dt (gradient)
3. normal(t) is a(t) normal acceleration = dv/dt
4. binormal(b) is result of vectorial product b(t) = a(t)  x  v (t)

The binormal(b), normal(a) and  tangent(v)vectors define the coordinate orthogonal local system along a space curve(r) - see ***fig 2.6*** from node24.html article.

So, if have memorized the calculated local values of  b(= a x v), n(= a = dv/dt) and v(= dr/dt) I can use one transformation from BNV system into XYZ(translation from one coordinate system into other; both are orthogonal systems) to obtain the x,y,z coordinates;
In conclusion any point(x,y,z) from XYZ will be write as linear combination of its projected point from BNV system.

In physics see motion equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion

You can see that and in this math document(slides 3 and 5):
[https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~sjrob/Teaching/Vectors/](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Esjrob/Teaching/Vectors/)

**Remarks**:

-Do not forget that some n-derivable function can be decomposed as linear combination of functions like sin and cos(see **Fourier**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)

-In plus do not forget about this composed functions(useful rule when need to differentiate): http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Calculus/ChainRule/decompose.html#vma

**Conclusions**:

-If find one 3D - parametric function(=algorithm) for one 3d-body(= 3d model = 3d object) then can draw it in 3d-space;

-The parametrization is not single method to draw 3D bodies(3D-objects)...
for example can use rotation of 2D-function to obtain it!

Or, see another way instead of parametrization to obtain the 3D bodies:  Tube(extrusion along path) Image as intersection result of two prisms in http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_cylinder.html
and this calculation of P'(projection point P into intersection plane of two prisms) as projection obtained from P(point from initial face/profile)  to https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld017.htm

(this method of extrusion which have as inputs one set of points for profie=initial face and path, can be improved to obtain smooth path or profile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline,

https://jiharu.github.io/intm3d/week03.html,

[https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Interpolation.html](https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/%7Emflanaga/java/Interpolation.html)

or, see onother smoother  Kockanek-Bartel(KB) named aka Tension-Continuity-Bias-spline(alias TCB):
https://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/com/sun/j3d/utils/behaviors/interpolators/package-summary.html)

-But do not forget that what you can obtain using these methods is only one cloud of points(not entire 3d model) which approximate the 3D-curve.

One model is fully defined if know the cloud of points, edges and normals of faces(see one Poisson-reconstruction based on cloud of points at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/index.html ).

Please remarks the force of *algebra vector3D* (or *3D-vectorial algebra*)!!!